# SQL query to do division

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help to on below SQL query which will divide the first set of query with second one.

```
SELECT 
FROM 
(
  SELECT `Business_Unit`, 
   COUNT(`Joining_Month`) AS A 
  FROM `jl` 
  WHERE `Final_Status` = 'Joined' 
   AND `Source_wise` = 'Referral' 
   AND `Hiring_Catg` IN ('Lateral','Contract Conversion') 
  GROUP BY `Business_Unit`
) 
DIV 
(
  SELECT `Business_Unit`, 
   COUNT(`Joining_Month`) AS B 
  FROM `jl` 
  WHERE `Final_Status` = 'Joined' 
   AND `Hiring_Catg` IN ('Lateral','Contract Conversion') 
  GROUP BY `Business_Unit`
) ;
```

Comment: What happens? Do you execute this code? Is that a placeholder?

Comment: I am using MYSQL Database

Comment: Should you be joining on business unit and then dividing the counts?  Add sample data from both queries and expected results using that sample data.  Be sure to include multiple business_Units of different and same values and some in the first query not in second and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The query you posted is a dead-end; it cannot be made to work in that direction.

I would try to count the number of rows that pass the condition `Source_wise = 'Referral'` and the total number of rows for each group and then compute their ratio.

The query is something like this:

```
SELECT `Business_Unit`,
    SUM(IF(`Source_wise` = 'Referral', 1, 0)) AS ref
    COUNT(`Joining_Month`) AS total
FROM `jl`
WHERE `Final_Status` = 'Joined'
   AND `Hiring_Catg` IN ('Lateral','Contract Conversion')
GROUP BY `Business_Unit`
```

You have to compute `ref/total` for each row in the client code. Or you can compute it directly by changing the query above.